# How to choose position when zoom in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, position, zooming

i use stream

```
ffmpeg -i smed.ts -filter_complex "scale=640:360, crop=1/3*in_w:1/3*in_h" smed3.ts
```

but it only in mid video ,but i want it in right corner video .please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
crop=iw/3:ih/3:iw*2/3:0
```

for top-right corner.

```
crop=iw/3:ih/3:iw*2/3:ih*2/3
```

for bottom-right corner.

```
crop=iw/3:ih/3:iw*2/3
```

for middle-right.